# Populate the device data contents from thingsboad on mobile?

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ionic4, thingsboard

I have this device data that are shown in real time using ThingsBoard.

And I have an iframe to show the device data content on a web page.

If I used the same iframe on my ionic app's HTML page, I am getting all the header, submenu and other unnecessary things that are not needed in the app.

What I need is the main content area of the device data section.

Can I do that with the iframe or do I need to call all the individual ThingsBoard API's to populate the dashboard on my own?

Comment: If you have to display in your custom design and have manage by you then you have to thingsboard api for sure.

Comment: What if it's not?

Comment: Then you cannot display in your format as you want.

Comment: So what will I do then?

Comment: Are you sure there is not api available?

Comment: api i dont know.but for the iframe it does. can we do it that way?

Comment: We cannot do anything with iframe

Comment: So what you mean is calling a bunch of apis and displaying all the necessary data in the app?

Comment: Yes if we have to display data in our custom layout and design we have to call api only

Comment: so for each of the data that needs to be shown then we call multiple api's right>

Comment: also can you look at this post's answer, posted by @umair. He is talking about custom iframe. Can this be done?

Comment: they asking to do web scraping things. If there is pagination. It's not working

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192561/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-kevin-red).

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing the Thingsboard then you can develop custom iframes with unnecessary headers/footers removed. Then you will get clean iframes to display inside your Ionic app.

In case the Thingsboard is not managed by you then you have to develop adapters to scrape the html data from the Webpage. These adapters will provide your Ionic app only the data you require.

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for implementing these data scraping adapters.
[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://www.codementor.io/wang90925/top-10-best-usage-examples-of-php-simple-html-dom-parser-i8ik76e16)

Comment: can you explain how to do the custom iframe things in thingsboard?